# How to find the "widest" path between two nodes in a given graph (via built-in functions)?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The resource function [`ResourceFunction["FindLongestPath"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/f83b39a2-ac8f-4fae-8c4f-638534efd2b2/) can be used to solve the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), but Wikipedia also has an article on the so-called [widest path problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275742/fundamental-differences-between-widest-path-and-longest-path-problems). I find that there is an "[igraph C library](https://igraph.org/c/html/develop/igraph-Structural.html#igraph_get_widest_path)" that provides an implementation; unfortunately, I am really not familiar with and, in effect,  have no time to study something like building from sources on Windows and CMake. (And though there exists an igraph interface for Mathematica, the IGraph/M does not offer such a functionality at present.) So, is there an effortless way to `FindWidestPath` from a single vertex to another one (assuming that one graph has been generated randomly in advance) in modern Mathematica?

Comment: Feel free to open a feature request in the IGraph/M repo so that this feature could be exposed. I will try to do it in September, but I need a reminder.